# Exception line numbers are messed-up on CCNET build reports

Tags: .net, exception, continuous-integration, reporting, line-numbers

We are having an integration server (CruiseControl.NET) building and validating a couple of .NET 3.5 libraries. When some integration code fails, the exception is logged and appears in a custom report.

Yet, the line numbers reported by the exception messages are messed-up - usually short from 50 / 100 lines below the place where the exception has been thrown.

Any idea what could cause such a situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your build process insert any headers in the source code?  If so, then you might see an offset between line numbers on your workstation and those on the build server.

Alternatively, you might have changed your build process to no longer create PDB files, giving you old line numbers for newer builds.

Unfortunately, because CCNet configuration is so tailored to your situation, it's hard to diagnose without more information.  I would recommend comparing the source code on the build machine's disk with that on your workstation and seeing whether the reported line numbers are accurate for the server's copy of the files.

You might also try forcing a clean source checkout and delete any lingering build output.

Comment: Lines numbers are changing when the code is changed - yet, there is not constant offset. We do not have code preprocessing (that would insert headers for example). But thanks for the idea.